# How to provide 2 inputs in a bash script command?

Tags: linux, bash

I am trying to mount a remote folder on to my computer using sshfs.
my bash script is as follows:

```
sudo sshfs -o allow_other id@afs1.domain.com:/ /home/kr1shna/remote -o password_stdin <<<"xxxxxx"
```

and everytime i execute this, it prompts me for the root password.

so i tried:

```
echo "rootpassword" | sudo -S sshfs -o allow_other id@afs1.domain.com:/ /home/kr1shna/remote -o password_stdin <<<"xxxxxx"
```

I know its not a good habit to echo my root password, but I'm the only one who uses this computer.

In what way can I provide the root password and the other password parameter in the bash script?

Thank you.

Comment: This post (https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/337465/username-and-password-in-command-line-with-sshfs) has a very good alternative to echoing your password, using private and public keys.

Comment: There only *can ever be* one stdin stream to a process. You can put two different lines of input into that stream, but you can't make there be two separate streams.

Comment: Anyhow, why not just configure `sudo` to not prompt for a password when running this command?

Comment: `printf '%s\n' 'rootpassword' 'xxxxxx' | sudo -S sshfs -o allow_other id@afs1.domain.com:/ /home/kr1shna/remote -o password_stdin` is an example of the two-separate-lines approach. You could also write that as `<<<$'rootpasswd\nxxxxxx'` without an `echo`. But all the above is ugly, evil, insecure hackery, and shouldn't ever be done by anyone.

Comment: ("I'm the only one who uses this computer" is not at all an excuse -- you don't need to worry about *authorized* users, after all, because by nature they're people you trust; instead you need to worry about malware running under your own account -- or an untrusted account like `nobody` used by network services -- sneaking around trying to read any plaintext password it can find -- which is why it's so much better to store private keys in hardware stores, where software *can't possibly* copy them out).

Comment: `sudo` doesn't ask for the root password, it asks for *your* password.

Answer (score 0):

Try defining the values you want to pass to a command.

For example

```
password="$(echo 'HelloWorld!')";
echo "Your password is $password";
```

In your case, it would be:

```
password="$(echo 'xxxxx')"
sudo sshfs -o allow_other id@afs1.domain.com:/ /home/kr1shna/remote -p $password
```

And I know you're probably getting annoyed with us all telling you to not do this, but this really does pose a potential security flaw to your server. I would **highly** recommend against doing this.

Comment: why not just `password="HelloWorld!"` and `password="xxxx"`?? Good luck to all.

Comment: I suppose that would work... I've been working on a lot of scripts that would mistake the output of that variable as a file directory, so I guess it was a force of habit(?). Either way, you are correct. `password="HelloWorld!"` and `password="xxxxx"` would work.

Answer (score 0):

Why not generate the ssh pub keys and login ssh without inputting password. Lots of distributed clusters do it this way.